# fix header on mobile version

Tags: html, css, prestashop-1.6

at our site www.ftina-pc.gr (prestashop based) I need to align the mobile menu with the logo. 
I have tried float etc but can't find a way to fix this. 
The desktop version is OK. only the mobile version has the problem. 
I have attached a mockup on how it should look. 
Can anyone please help me ?

Kind Regards[image]

Comment: What does the CSS look like? Please give an example of what you've done already and what you've tried to fix the problem.

Comment: Before we can help you, we need you to [edit] your question and add some additional details: (1) an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), (2) a detailed description of the error or problematic output you're getting, and (3) your goal. See [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

`display:inline-block;` on both elements and give them fixed percentage `width`. Post your code if you want more detail from someone

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {  
    // something
}
```

And so on have you tried to do different styles for mobile and desktop? That might be problem.

Comment: And you have actually inherited line-height: 22px; from body in pc so is there another value on mobile?

Comment: Yes I am using  @media (max-width: 767px) for this.  atm I managed to move the logo image using the code position: relative;
    z-index: 98;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;  but can't find a way to move the mobile menu at the top

Answer (score 0):

So to solve this I did this (always under @media (max-width: 768px):

```
#logo-theme.logo-theme {width:80%;}
.pts-megamenu .navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: -60px !important;
    z-index: 99;
}
.pts-megamenu .navbar{min-height: 0px !important}
```

Hope this makes sense. 
Seems to work though. if Anyone cares to look at the code it is would be great!

thanks everyone